# Solution for javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake in JMeter

Tags: ssl, jmeter, sslhandshakeexception

### Summary of the issue:

### Tool - JMeter , version 3.0

I am testing a application with login form and am getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException for .js,Css and png child request of parent login request.

This issue occurs when I try to execute more then 1 users simultaneously.
I have tried the following ways to solve but not luck so far.

```
http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
httpclient4.retrycount=1
httpclient.parameters.file=httpclient.parameters
implementation = HttpClient4
port = 443
```

I have had a word with the dev team and as per them there is no issue from 
server side configuration.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue.
Appreciate quick feedback.

Thanks,
Brij

Comment: Here is the error message "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake".....Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly....

Comment: What sampler are you using? And all in all, it would be helpful if you shed some light on how your suite is built.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, that is caused by protocol mismatch - e.g., the client is trying to start it in SSLv2, while server allows only TLS, or SSLv3 and TLS (and that is for reason).

But having that reproducible in case of multiple connections only... pretty much looks like an issue/feature on server.

I suggest you to doublecheck it with whoever is resposible for the server, and/or dig into the server connection logs to see what's going on at the other side.

And show your suite, that *may* help.